# Charging capacity and capacitance of a conductor

Tags: electric-fields, potential, charge, capacitance, dielectric

I know that charging capacity of a conductor is the maximum charge a conductor can hold And capacitance is the ability of a conductor to hold charge in a given potential . But how are these two quantities related?

Comment: Did you mean q = c/v

Comment: @VaibhavSingh What is q and v ? I mean  q I guess you are saying the maximum capacity but what is v ?

Answer (score 1):

$\text{Capacitance of a Conductor=  }$$\frac{\text{charging capacity of conductor}}{\text{Breakdown potential of dielectric}}$

Answer (score 0):

The capacitance of a capacitor depends on the dielectric constant (relative permittivity) between the plates.
The maximum charge that can be stored on a capacitor depends on the maximum potential difference across the plates of the capacitor which in turn depends on the maximum electric field (breakdown potential gradient - dielectric strength) which the dielectric can sustain before it becomes a conductor.

I know of no simple relationship between the dielectric constant and dielectric strength of a dielectric.

Assume a parallel plate capacitor with a constant area $A$ of the plates and with a dielectric of permittivity $\epsilon$ between the plates and $d$ is their separation.
The capacitance is $\frac {\epsilon A}{d}$ and so the charge stored $Q = \epsilon A \frac {V}{d}$ where $V$ is the potential difference across the plates.

The electric field between the plates $\frac V d$ is limited by the dielectric strength of the dielectric and so this limits the maximum which can be stored on a capacitor.

Comment: I am asking about the capacitance of a conductor (general) not a two plate capacitor.

Comment: The definition of capacitance includes a potential difference between two parts of the capacitor one of which could be a long way away from the other.  The more a conductor is curved then the larger will be the electric field near its surface and so this will increase the probability of the dielectric becoming a conductor.  That is why high voltage equipment is designed not to have sharp edges and the use of bundled conductors in overhead power lines.

Comment: Capacitance is always referred to something. Like, the second plate of a spherical capacitor is referred at infinity.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard about charging capacity, at least in the context I suppose you're referring to.
Limiting the discussion to one isolated conductor which carries a charge $Q$, the conductor has a certain potential $\phi_0$, assuming zero potential at infinity. What happens is that $Q$ is proportional to $\phi_0$ and the constant of proportionality depends only on the size and shape of the conductor. Then, this constant is named *capacitance* and it can be denoted by $C$ so that:
$$
Q=C\phi_0
$$
Just an example, the potential of an isolated charged spheric conductor is simply
$$
V=\frac{Q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 R}.
$$
From here you can put on the conductor as much charge as you like, its potential will change accordingly. You can also see that the capacitance of the isolated spherical conductor is
$$
C=\frac{Q}{V}=4\pi\varepsilon_0 R
$$